# How can I store "data" attributes in a Node inside a contentEditable container?

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

I'm making a `mention` system for comments, similar to facebook's, but I can't figure out how to store mention's ID.

So I have this:

```
<div contenteditable>
  <span data-id="123">Peter</span> is a good person
</div>
```

However, when looking at **the actual HTML generated by the browser**, it completely removes the `data-id` attribute:

```
<div contenteditable>
  <span>Peter</span> is a good person
</div>
```

What is the right approach here?

Comment: _"However, when looking at the actual HTML generated by the browser, it completely removes the `data-id` attribute:"_ Cannot reproduce

Answer (score 0):

`data-` attributes are visible in the DOM under normal circumstances, and to access them, you need to target the `dataset` of that element in JS.

E.g.

```js
let div = document.getElementById('span');

console.log(div.dataset);
```

```html
<div contenteditable>
  <span id="span" data-id="123">Peter</span> is a good person
</div>
```